# SO_REUSEADDR Is there a limit of sockets can use the same address ?

Tags: c, network-programming

IS there a maximum number of socket can limit the REUSEADDR socket operation.
I reached the maximum number of file descriptors but I could use the same address and port to the all sockets, is there a limit of number of reuse address operations ???? 
if there, how can i get the number

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the socket is for. If it's a TCP listening socket, you can only have one of those at a time per interface, and all that SO_REUSEADDR lets you do is ignore any remaining connected ports that are now in TIME_WAIT state. If it's an outbound TCP connection I don't even know the answer. If it's a multicast UDP receiving port you can have as many as you like.

Answer (score 0):

In your server set the host to "0.0.0.0". This will force the socket to listen on any interface. This could be one of the issues.